# What Arabic web font is this website using?

Tags: font-identification, web-fonts, arabic

Can you help me find what kind of Arabic web font [this website](http://www.t-voice.net/blog/2017/05/11/%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%84-%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%B0-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89-beddit-%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%B9%D9%83-%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%89-%D8%BA%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%A9-%D9%86%D9%88%D9%85%D9%83/) is using?

[image]

Comment: note: this font support Arabic not just English letters

Comment: See [How can I know what fonts a website is using?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65366/52050) ...I answered here since it was a bit more involved, but generally you can just use the methods in that question to get the font name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I know what fonts a website is using?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65366/how-can-i-know-what-fonts-a-website-is-using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Neo Sans; licensed by Linotype.

https://www.linotype.com/de/156438/neo-sans-schriftfamilie.html

[image]

The font names on the site were obscured (see e.g. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGmd5.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A50TZ.png)) so it took downloading the font files themselves and [checking the meta data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIPob.png) to find out the actual font name...

Comment: No idea why you don't have more votes for this, but nice work.

Answer (score -2):

font-family: "BDNR", Arial, sans-serif shows in the inspect