# what's the font used in the Mahou Tsukai Precure Asahi website?

Tags: font-identification, japanese

Can someone please help me identify this font? I know it's not Meiryo...but it's something similar...I've checked most of the Japanese font websites but still found nothing...

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I know what fonts a website is using?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65366/how-can-i-know-what-fonts-a-website-is-using)

Answer (score 1):

They are certainly nothing standard like Meiryo, they are what Japanese font makers designate as デサインフォント, or Design Fonts. The fonts in the image are all made by [DynaComware](http://www.dynacw.co.jp/). The Image is made by combining 2 typefaces, one of them in two styles. The first part, キュアミラクル, was made with the ロマン鳳 (roman ōtori) family, specifically using the font [DFロマン鳳B Std W7](http://www.dynacw.co.jp/product/product_download_detail.aspx?sid=1405), substituting the ミ with [DFロマン鳳A Std W7](http://www.dynacw.co.jp/product/product_download_detail.aspx?sid=1402). They were most probably tweaked to look bolder and the final ル de-squared. Here are the font samplers from the site:

DFロマン鳳B Std W7
[image: DynaFonts Roman Ootori Font Sample]

DFロマン鳳A Std W7
[image: DynaFonts Roman Ootori FontSample]

The second part, 朝日奈みらい, was made with the typeface ロマン雪 (Roman Yuki), specifically [DFロマン雪B Std W9](http://www.dynacw.co.jp/product/product_download_detail.aspx?sid=1406). It seems it was used as-is. Here comes the sample:

DFロマン雪B Std W9
[image: DynaFonts Roman Yuki Font Sample]

And that's it! Colors, gradients, outlines and drop shadows were most surely made post-type in Illustrator or something like that. :P すてきないちにちを
!

BTW, DynaComware makes some interesting fonts, [check them out](http://www.dynacw.co.jp/fileupload/downfile/2017_sougo.pdf).

EDIT: After checking again the glyphs, for the first part, I think they only used Roman Yuki, combining some Katakanas from both the A and B versions of the font.