# can you identify this font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation, web-fonts, font-licensing

so I am looking to find the fonts thats being used on the cartier.co.uk website or as similar as possible?

here's the 2 fonts I am looking for - 
[image]

thank you!
:)

Comment: Hi Dor Adam Bukobza, we have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information. Thanks!

Comment: If you're looking for the fonts used on a live website have a look at some of the methods described here: [How can I know what fonts a website is using?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65366/52050)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to identify fonts from a website, it's easy to use the DevTool inspector.

So, I had a look and found "Didot" for Newsletter and "ProximaNovaSemibold" for the rest.

Comment: oh wow I didnt know theres a tool like that! thank you!!!

Comment: where can I get it from? (the tool)

Comment: @DorAdamBukobza There are inspector tools built into browsers, such as Firefox (Inspector), and Chrome (DevTools).

Comment: See Cai's comment to your original post