# what is this font used in the blog?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

[image]

I tried multiple webpages to identify the font, but I only got something similar. Not the same font.
This font is taken from 'That's chic' blog!
Thank you!!

Comment: please read this https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65366/how-can-i-know-what-fonts-a-website-is-using/68339#68339

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I know what fonts a website is using?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65366/how-can-i-know-what-fonts-a-website-is-using)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) (right click on a text and select "Inspect") you'll find out that the font is called **[Larish Neue Semibold](https://radimpesko.com/fonts/larish-neue)**:

[image]

Comment: I do remember the Discman. Next question.

Comment: @Joonas I thought someone would :)