# What font is Google using across many apps (not Roboto)

Tags: fonts, font-identification, google-material-design

I noticed Google is using this font specially in small CardViews and it's doing a very good job together with the rounded corners of the cards. Any one have an idea what this font is?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  If this is from a web page, there are various browser plugins which will let you inspect the various elements on the page to determine the font.  See this related question: [How can I know what fonts a website is using](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65366/how-can-i-know-what-fonts-a-website-is-using)

Answer (score 1):

This is Google's proprietary Product Sans. It's not publicly available, but Proxima, FF Mark, Gotham and ITC Kabel are in the same space.