# Whats is the font used in this code snippet

Tags: font-identification

[image: the code picture]

I really want to find the name of this font please anyone help me

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. To identify fonts on a web page you should inspect the HTML/CSS using a web browser on your computer. See this question for more information: [How can I know what font a website is using](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65366/how-can-i-know-what-fonts-a-website-is-using)

Comment: Since this doesn't appear to be needed for any kind of fine art typography, specifically for coding, any kind of monospace font probably works.

Answer (score 1):

The font is called '[Hack](https://github.com/source-foundry/Hack)' a 'Monospace' font.

You can download the latest version of the font [here](https://github.com/source-foundry/Hack/releases).

Also if you are using Chrome, there's an extension you can install to identify fonts from websites. [WhatFont](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

It might be `cascadia-code`, an open-source monospace by Microsoft. There [the font source files](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code#welcome) and here you [can download the latest version](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases).

In case you are having the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The monospace means that any character takes the same width as the others. This helps with the readability of the code. Usually, all code snippet fonts are using monospace fonts.

I would suggest searching for any monospace font that will suit your license and estetic needs.